# Convert code from SSE2 to SSE4 in C

Tags: c++, sse, simd

I have to convert a vector optimization C code from sse2 to sse4 .I am using a x86_64  machine with Ubuntu 14.1 and a gcc built-in compiler.How do I go about it ?

edit 1: This is a stub of the code I am trying to modify using SSE 4 C intrinsics . Any changes in the code by using SSE 4 methods will be really help

```
    void pLayer(word *X, word *Y) {
      X[ 0] = Y[ 0],  X[ 1] = Y[ 4],  X[ 2] = Y[ 8],  X[ 3] = Y[12];
      X[ 4] = Y[16],  X[ 5] = Y[20],  X[ 6] = Y[24],  X[ 7] = Y[28];
      X[ 8] = Y[32],  X[ 9] = Y[36],  X[10] = Y[40],  X[11] = Y[44];
      X[12] = Y[48],  X[13] = Y[52],  X[14] = Y[56],  X[15] = Y[60];
      X[16] = Y[ 1],  X[17] = Y[ 5],  X[18] = Y[ 9],  X[19] = Y[13];
      X[20] = Y[17],  X[21] = Y[21],  X[22] = Y[25],  X[23] = Y[29];
      X[24] = Y[33],  X[25] = Y[37],  X[26] = Y[41],  X[27] = Y[45];
      X[28] = Y[49],  X[29] = Y[53],  X[30] = Y[57],  X[31] = Y[61];
      X[32] = Y[ 2],  X[33] = Y[ 6],  X[34] = Y[10],  X[35] = Y[14];
      X[36] = Y[18],  X[37] = Y[22],  X[38] = Y[26],  X[39] = Y[30];
      X[40] = Y[34],  X[41] = Y[38],  X[42] = Y[42],  X[43] = Y[46];
      X[44] = Y[50],  X[45] = Y[54],  X[46] = Y[58],  X[47] = Y[62];
      X[48] = Y[ 3],  X[49] = Y[ 7],  X[50] = Y[11],  X[51] = Y[15];
      X[52] = Y[19],  X[53] = Y[23],  X[54] = Y[27],  X[55] = Y[31];
      X[56] = Y[35],  X[57] = Y[39],  X[58] = Y[43],  X[59] = Y[47];
      X[60] = Y[51],  X[61] = Y[55],  X[62] = Y[59],  X[63] = Y[63];
    }

    void encrypt(word *X, const word *subkeys, const size_t nr) {
      static word Y[Bs];
      for(size_t i=0; i<nr;i++) {
        addRoundKey(X, subkeys + (i*Bs));
        sBoxLayer(Y, X);
        pLayer(X, Y);
      }
      addRoundKey(X, subkeys + (nr*Bs));
    }


    void rotate(word *k) {
      word temp[Ks];
      memcpy(temp,k,Ks*sizeof(word));
      for(size_t i =0; i<Ks; i++) {
        k[i] = temp[(i+61)%Ks];
      }
    }
void addRoundKey(word *X, const word *K) {
  //unsigned long long a,b,c,d;
  //a=X[0],b=K[0],c=X[1],d=K[1];
  /*var=_mm_xor_si128 (_mm_set_epi64x(X[0],X[1]),_mm_set_epi64x(K[0],K[1]));
  unsigned long long *v64val = (int64_t*) &var;
  X[0]=v64val[1],X[1] =v64val[0];*/
  //printf("here %llu %llu %llu \n %llu %llu %llu\n",a,b,c,d,v64val[0],v64val[1]);
  //X[0]= X[0]^K[0];  X[1] = X[1]^K[1];
  //printf("here %llu %llu\n",X[0],X[1]);
  //usleep(10000*1000);
  XOR_word(X[0],X[1],K[0],K[1]);
  //X[ 2] ^= K[ 2],  X[ 3] ^= K[ 3];
  XOR_word(X[2],X[3],K[2],K[3]);
  //X[ 4] ^= K[ 4],  X[ 5] ^= K[ 5];  
  XOR_word(X[4],X[5],K[4],K[5]);
  //X[ 6] ^= K[ 6],  X[ 7] ^= K[ 7];
  XOR_word(X[6],X[7],K[6],K[7]);
  //X[ 8] ^= K[ 8],  X[ 9] ^= K[ 9];
  XOR_word(X[8],X[9],K[8],K[9]);  
  //X[10] ^= K[10],  X[11] ^= K[11];
  XOR_word(X[10],X[11],K[10],K[11]);
  //X[12] ^= K[12],  X[13] ^= K[13];  
  XOR_word(X[12],X[13],K[12],K[13]);
  //X[14] ^= K[14],  X[15] ^= K[15];
  XOR_word(X[14],X[15],K[14],K[15]);
  //X[16] ^= K[16],  X[17] ^= K[17];  
  XOR_word(X[16],X[17],K[16],K[17]);
  //X[18] ^= K[18],  X[19] ^= K[19];
  XOR_word(X[18],X[19],K[18],K[19]);
  //X[20] ^= K[20],  X[21] ^= K[21];  
  XOR_word(X[20],X[21],K[20],K[21]);
  //X[22] ^= K[22],  X[23] ^= K[23];
  XOR_word(X[22],X[23],K[22],K[23]);
  //X[24] ^= K[24],  X[25] ^= K[25];  
  XOR_word(X[24],X[25],K[24],K[25]);
  //X[26] ^= K[26],  X[27] ^= K[27];
  XOR_word(X[26],X[27],K[26],K[27]);
  //X[28] ^= K[28],  X[29] ^= K[29];  
  XOR_word(X[28],X[29],K[28],K[29]);
  //X[30] ^= K[30],  X[31] ^= K[31];
  XOR_word(X[30],X[31],K[30],K[31]);
  //X[32] ^= K[32],  X[33] ^= K[33];  
  XOR_word(X[32],X[33],K[32],K[33]);
  //X[34] ^= K[34],  X[35] ^= K[35];
  XOR_word(X[34],X[35],K[34],K[35]);
  //X[36] ^= K[36],  X[37] ^= K[37];  
  XOR_word(X[36],X[37],K[36],K[37]);
  //X[38] ^= K[38],  X[39] ^= K[39];
  XOR_word(X[38],X[39],K[38],K[39]);
  //X[40] ^= K[40],  X[41] ^= K[41];  
  XOR_word(X[40],X[41],K[40],K[41]);
  //X[42] ^= K[42],  X[43] ^= K[43];
  XOR_word(X[42],X[43],K[42],K[43]);
  //X[44] ^= K[44],  X[45] ^= K[45];  
  XOR_word(X[44],X[45],K[44],K[45]);
  //X[46] ^= K[46],  X[47] ^= K[47];
  XOR_word(X[46],X[47],K[46],K[47]);
  //X[48] ^= K[48],  X[49] ^= K[49];  
  XOR_word(X[48],X[49],K[48],K[49]);
  //X[50] ^= K[50],  X[51] ^= K[51];
  XOR_word(X[50],X[51],K[50],K[51]);
  //X[52] ^= K[52],  X[53] ^= K[53];  
  XOR_word(X[52],X[53],K[52],K[53]);
  //X[54] ^= K[54],  X[55] ^= K[55];
  XOR_word(X[54],X[55],K[54],K[55]);
  //X[56] ^= K[56],  X[57] ^= K[57];  
  XOR_word(X[56],X[57],K[56],K[57]);
  //X[58] ^= K[58],  X[59] ^= K[59];
  XOR_word(X[58],X[59],K[58],K[59]);
  //X[60] ^= K[60],  X[61] ^= K[61];  
  XOR_word(X[60],X[61],K[60],K[61]);
  //X[62] ^= K[62],  X[63] ^= K[63];
  XOR_word(X[63],X[63],K[63],K[63]);
}

void addRoundKey(word *X, const word *K) {
  //unsigned long long a,b,c,d;
  //a=X[0],b=K[0],c=X[1],d=K[1];
  /*var=_mm_xor_si128 (_mm_set_epi64x(X[0],X[1]),_mm_set_epi64x(K[0],K[1]));
  unsigned long long *v64val = (int64_t*) &var;
  X[0]=v64val[1],X[1] =v64val[0];*/
  //printf("here %llu %llu %llu \n %llu %llu %llu\n",a,b,c,d,v64val[0],v64val[1]);
  //X[0]= X[0]^K[0];  X[1] = X[1]^K[1];
  //printf("here %llu %llu\n",X[0],X[1]);
  //usleep(10000*1000);
  XOR_word(X[0],X[1],K[0],K[1]);
  //X[ 2] ^= K[ 2],  X[ 3] ^= K[ 3];
  XOR_word(X[2],X[3],K[2],K[3]);
  //X[ 4] ^= K[ 4],  X[ 5] ^= K[ 5];  
  XOR_word(X[4],X[5],K[4],K[5]);
  //X[ 6] ^= K[ 6],  X[ 7] ^= K[ 7];
  XOR_word(X[6],X[7],K[6],K[7]);
  //X[ 8] ^= K[ 8],  X[ 9] ^= K[ 9];
  XOR_word(X[8],X[9],K[8],K[9]);  
  //X[10] ^= K[10],  X[11] ^= K[11];
  XOR_word(X[10],X[11],K[10],K[11]);
  //X[12] ^= K[12],  X[13] ^= K[13];  
  XOR_word(X[12],X[13],K[12],K[13]);
  //X[14] ^= K[14],  X[15] ^= K[15];
  XOR_word(X[14],X[15],K[14],K[15]);
  //X[16] ^= K[16],  X[17] ^= K[17];  
  XOR_word(X[16],X[17],K[16],K[17]);
  //X[18] ^= K[18],  X[19] ^= K[19];
  XOR_word(X[18],X[19],K[18],K[19]);
  //X[20] ^= K[20],  X[21] ^= K[21];  
  XOR_word(X[20],X[21],K[20],K[21]);
  //X[22] ^= K[22],  X[23] ^= K[23];
  XOR_word(X[22],X[23],K[22],K[23]);
  //X[24] ^= K[24],  X[25] ^= K[25];  
  XOR_word(X[24],X[25],K[24],K[25]);
  //X[26] ^= K[26],  X[27] ^= K[27];
  XOR_word(X[26],X[27],K[26],K[27]);
  //X[28] ^= K[28],  X[29] ^= K[29];  
  XOR_word(X[28],X[29],K[28],K[29]);
  //X[30] ^= K[30],  X[31] ^= K[31];
  XOR_word(X[30],X[31],K[30],K[31]);
  //X[32] ^= K[32],  X[33] ^= K[33];  
  XOR_word(X[32],X[33],K[32],K[33]);
  //X[34] ^= K[34],  X[35] ^= K[35];
  XOR_word(X[34],X[35],K[34],K[35]);
  //X[36] ^= K[36],  X[37] ^= K[37];  
  XOR_word(X[36],X[37],K[36],K[37]);
  //X[38] ^= K[38],  X[39] ^= K[39];
  XOR_word(X[38],X[39],K[38],K[39]);
  //X[40] ^= K[40],  X[41] ^= K[41];  
  XOR_word(X[40],X[41],K[40],K[41]);
  //X[42] ^= K[42],  X[43] ^= K[43];
  XOR_word(X[42],X[43],K[42],K[43]);
  //X[44] ^= K[44],  X[45] ^= K[45];  
  XOR_word(X[44],X[45],K[44],K[45]);
  //X[46] ^= K[46],  X[47] ^= K[47];
  XOR_word(X[46],X[47],K[46],K[47]);
  //X[48] ^= K[48],  X[49] ^= K[49];  
  XOR_word(X[48],X[49],K[48],K[49]);
  //X[50] ^= K[50],  X[51] ^= K[51];
  XOR_word(X[50],X[51],K[50],K[51]);
  //X[52] ^= K[52],  X[53] ^= K[53];  
  XOR_word(X[52],X[53],K[52],K[53]);
  //X[54] ^= K[54],  X[55] ^= K[55];
  XOR_word(X[54],X[55],K[54],K[55]);
  //X[56] ^= K[56],  X[57] ^= K[57];  
  XOR_word(X[56],X[57],K[56],K[57]);
  //X[58] ^= K[58],  X[59] ^= K[59];
  XOR_word(X[58],X[59],K[58],K[59]);
  //X[60] ^= K[60],  X[61] ^= K[61];  
  XOR_word(X[60],X[61],K[60],K[61]);
  //X[62] ^= K[62],  X[63] ^= K[63];
  XOR_word(X[63],X[63],K[63],K[63]);
}
```

Comment: Question doesn't make much sense - is the SSE code written in assembler or using C intrinsics ? And can you at least show us some or all of the relevant code ?

Comment: sorry for the late reply .I am using c intrinsics over time i have modified the code a bit by using sse 2 basic methods.I would like to somehow use  sse 4 functions and see the performance of my code.

Comment: I don't see any code using SSE2 intrinsics in the code you just added ?

Comment: i added it in the end see now just a XOR function of   emmintrin.h library

Comment: It's not clear how you would expect to improve on a simple XOR intrinsic wi SSE4 ? If you have AVX2 you could double the SIMD width.

Comment: can you suggest a few sse 4 intrinsic functions for the remaining code .I mean ,which functions of smmintrin.h (SSE 4) can be applied to a given function say  rotate() or pLayer()

Comment: How is `word` defined ?

Comment: typedef uint64_t word;

Comment: Since all you're doing is these two functions is shuffling data around, and the element size is 64 bits, I don't see any way to benefit from SIMD. There are probably some higher level optimisations that you should be looking at before considering SIMD.

Comment: Please can you share some link or a reference to any such optimization which you feel might optimize the code

Comment: Well you could start with Intel's optimisation manual: http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf - read a few books on algorithms and high performance computing too, e.g. Programming Pearls and the O'Reilly High Performance Computing book. Read some of the relevant questions and answers right here on StackOverflow too (e.g. anything tagged with `[simd]` or `[performance]`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some new SIMD instructions in [SSE4.1](https://software.intel.com/ru-ru/node/514241) (and also in [SSE3](https://software.intel.com/ru-ru/node/514268) and [SSSE3](https://software.intel.com/ru-ru/node/514259)) compared with [SSE2](https://software.intel.com/ru-ru/node/514275). These new operations may improve performance of your code.
But I can't recommend anything specific because I do not see your code.
There is some examples of optimization from SSE2 to SSSE3 (it is my project):

http://simd.sourceforge.net/